# Firestore Rules Not Working At All with Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /pool/{poolId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote the previous rules by following https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents.
I expected that, for a user to add a new document into the collection `pool`, a document of the ID `request.auth.uid` should exist in the collection `user` and have an entry `admin: true` .

But every request from Functions

```
    pool.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
        const added = await db.collection('pool').add({
            ...
        }); 
    });
```

is allowed to add a new document to the collection `pool`.

Even the following rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /pool/{poolId} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

do not disallow any requests from Functions...

What's the problem of the rules? Or, is there something in Functions which makes the rules not working? Or, in my project configuration...?

Comment: Firebase functions works as "super admin". You can literally change rules in your database if you want using functions. You need to write your own logic in functions to secure your functions.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "request from Functions"? Where is the request executed? In a **Cloud Function**? I guess that with `pool.post` you pass an  Express app to your HTTP Cloud Function.

Comment: @Mises, the last config he showed should prevent anything from writing, but functions can still write, so there is an issue. Yes, he could check `context.auth.admin` === `true` at the top of his function and reject the request, but the question was why is the `Firestore rules` way of securing `Firestore` against unauthed function calls does not work. I think your point is valid though and something that can be done *in addition* to what he's asking as an extra security measure. --- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

Comment: @Mises Then the rules work for what...? Aren't the rules for requests coming into the Firestore Database from anywhere...?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I am using Firebase Functions to add a document to a Firestore Database.

Comment: @ghchoi Rules works for calls straight to a database. For example, using Firebase JavaScript SDK library. The user browser can make calls to the database if rules allow him to.

Comment: @Mises What should I do if I want to allow only requests from specific users? Should I use the condition like `if (db.collection('user').get(request.auth.uid))`...?

Comment: @ghchoi There are many possibilities to do that. One way is like you have in your question. But you have to restrict access to "user" collection so only "super admin" can change documents there (Well not only, but it's just an example). Second one is to check user token: `request.auth.token.admin == true` but you will need to write a firebase function to assign this field to a user token.

Comment: Your question is very common.  Please read the duplicates to understand the behavior.  The bottom line is that you can't control the queries coming from backends, only from frontends when using the web and mobile SDKs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions for Firebase use the Node.js [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) which **totally bypasses the security rules** since it is considered as a "privileged environment".

You'll find a note on this aspect in the Firestore [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions):

> Note: The server client libraries bypass all Cloud Firestore Security
> Rules

---

If you want to restrict your HTTPS Cloud Function to only the Firebase users of your app (and identify which user is calling it through the decoded ID token) you can follow the following Firebase official Cloud Function sample: [Authorized HTTPS Endpoint](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/authorized-https-endpoint).

Comment: What should I do if I want to allow only requests from specific users? Should I use the condition like `if (db.collection('user').get(request.auth.uid))`...?

Comment: I really don't understand where to use the rules then... Can't I make my Functions not bypass the security rules?

Comment: See the update for restricting your HTTPS Cloud Function to only the Firebase users of your app. For "I really don't understand where to use the rules then" => Rules are enforced when the **Client SDKs** calls the Firestore serverless backend. The **Server SDKs** bypass them.

Comment: Can you please help me a little bit more? I followed Authorized HTTPS Endpoint. 
 What I additionally want to do is allowing only some of authorized users to write into the collection 'pool' while all authorized users can read the collection.

Comment: So I may change `const { initializeApp, applicationDefault } = require('firebase-admin/app');` to use `Client SDKs`?

Comment: No don't use the Clients SDKs and keep using the Admin SDK. As shown at lines [61 to 63](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/539345b1d7b3af7a7fd4fadaa54255329bdff3e3/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L61) in the sample, the Firebase ID token that was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header is decoded and you can get the user uid (req.user.uid). You must write a logic in your Cloud Function that authorizes (or not) a user identified by its uid to execute a specific action (read or write).

Comment: Note that the following sentence in my last comment "authorizes (or not) a user identified by its uid to execute a specific action" may be confusing. Actually the action (read or write from/to the `pool`collection) is no executed by the user but **by the Cloud Function**. And in the Cloud Function, you get the caller's uid (see above comment) and decide if you can write or read to/from the collection based on this uid. in other words the Cloud Function acts as an application server or a middleware.

Comment: Thanks master. I learned a lot. Now I can move lots of Function's code to Flutter. I did not even know Flutter can directly CRUD Firestore... I thought I need a backend to communicate with Firestore DB. Now it seems clearer to me! My question was closed but thanks again.